# autoHeight issue in ExtJS4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs3

We are using autoHeight to window in ExtJS3. But now in ExtJS4 it is not working. Is there any alternative to this one? If yes,please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read [this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?134032-autoHeight-autoWidth-How-is-this-done-in-ExtJS4) and [this](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?133148-autoHeight-feature), maybe it helps

Comment: Yes, you want to use a formal layout. This will be a great boon all around as you proceed.

Answer (score 1):

dont set the height property then it should automatically get height depending on content
it works for me,hope it will for u

Comment: Thanks for your reply.It will work but as per client requirement we need to set height when the client click on fieldset then autoHeight hs to execute i mean scrool bar has to appear in the window.Is there any chance to get this in ExtJS4?

Comment: im not exactly sure i understood what u want, but if u set autoScroll  : true  it will appear only when needed,meaning when the height will exceed the window

Comment: yes i want to display scroll bar when components in window are increased.I mean window height will be restricted but scrollbar has to appear.