# ExtJS 4 > Grid > Dynamically set height to fit any number of records

Tags: extjs

In my ExtJS 4 Grid, I would like to set the height dynamically upon loading the records.

For instance:

1. If my Grid loads 52 records, then it should show all the 52 records simultaneously (without any scroll-bar in the Grid).
2. If my Grid loads 73 records, then it should show all the 73 records simultaneously (without any scroll-bar in the Grid).

i.e. I don't need any scroll bars in the Grid. Instead, I would like to use browser's scroll-bar instead.

Do anyone has a solution ?

Comment: we need to know what version?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758298/autoheight-problem-in-extjs4

Comment: I don't think that's going to work, what you need to do is hook into the grid store's load event, calculate how many rows there are and then adjust the height of the grid accordingly... @AhsanAbdulJabbar you do realise that this could all be circumvented by using paging?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to handle the load event on the store of your grid, then change the grid height via

```
youGrid.getStore().on('load', function anonym(){
   myGrid.setHeight(this.getCount() * 16); // to be calculated
}
```

Of course, you have to resize all parent container of this grid

Comment: Some of my cells spanning 2-3 lines, how can I calculate that?

Answer (score 2):

if u dont specify a height property for your grid. this will solve it.

Comment: This works for me and seems to be the simplest solution. It also addresses digz6666's issue "Some of my cells spanning 2-3 lines, how can I calculate that?"

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help,
this was the answer, though if you are outside the grid initialization, something like this seams more appropriate:

`myGrid.getView().on('refresh', function () {
    var cellheight = 28;
    var titleHeight = 50;
    myGrid.setHeight(myGridStore.getCount() * cellheight + titleHeight);
});`

Answer (score 0):

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    id: "empDetails",
    store: store,
    columns: [{
        text: "Name",
        dataIndex: 'Name'
    }, {
        text: "Age",
        dataIndex: 'Age'
    }],
    renderTo: 'example-grid',
    forceFit: true,
    width: 300,
    ***getTotalHeight: function() {
        return "auto";
    },***
    dockedItems: [{
        xtype: 'toolbar',
        items: [{
                text: 'Employee Details'
            }

        ]
    }]

});
```